# help with this section of the work, arraylists objects lists

Tags: java

```
private List<MyShape> childShapes;
public ShapeCreator() {
    super();
    frame = new DrawGUI();
    this.childShapes = new ArrayList<MyShape>();
}
```

I have this piece of code and i have got to insert an infinite amount of data(the array size not fixed), which consists of integers, how would i do that, i think i must be getting confused with the this.childShapes

I would appreciate some help thanks

Comment: Where do you want to insert the data?

Comment: `childShapes.add(1); childShapes.add(2); //etc`?

Comment: An infinite amount of data? I don't think you've got the necessary amount of memory to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I could not say you formulated your question well enough... but i'll make my suggestion:

you probably want to have a method that will take the new data in as argument and insert it into the list of childShapes;

```
public void addShape(int whateverInt){
   childShapes.add(new MyShape(whateverInt));
}
```

That should do. You can call this method as many times as you like... until you run out of memory. There's no such thing as `infinite amount of data`. :-)